# PHP/Symfony/Twig forms and filtering for URL entries

Tags: php, symfony, twig-filter

I'm doing a school project in which I make a PHP/Symfony app. There is a form with a field which requires the user to enter an URL for an image hosted elsewhere. The problem is that when submitting the form, my hosting solution's firewall detects a 'Remote File Injection Attack'.

I tried to 'sanitize' the entry with a Twig filter (url_encode) however this does not seem to worl out (I'm quite the beginner as you may have realized by now)

I tried putting the filter after the 'row' :

```
{{ form_row(formformation.miniature)|url_encode() }}
```

... which encodes the entire field :
[image: field is html encoded]

Then i tried putting it inside the row :

```
{{ form_row(formformation.miniature|url_encode()) }}
```

... which gives an error as the parameter needs to be a string, not an object.

The field in question is a simple text type field (I tried UrlType, without success)

Extract from the form :

```
                ->add('miniature', TextType::class, [
                    'label' =>'Miniature (URL, taille 120x90 pixels)',
                    'required'=>false
                ])
```

Extract from the entity :

```
     * @Assert\Length(max=46,maxMessage = "L'url de la miniature ne peut pas excéder {{ limit }} caractères")
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=46, nullable=true)
     */
    private $miniature;
```

I tried other filters including 'raw', enabling/disabling autoescape, nothing seems to work.
I'm probably doing something very stupid :) Any ideas would be very much appreciated!
Many thanks,
Carl

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you want to encode the value that is entered by the user to bypass your firewall restrictions, you will need to do that with javascript in the client side - adding a listener to the form submit event for example and encoding the relevant value in the form data. In the above code you've been trying to encode the rendered html input/row - that happens on the server side before the page is served to the client - which doesn't have an effect on the value/format entered by the user on the client side.

Comment: Thank you! That does indeed make a lot of sense when I think about it... Thanks for reorienting my search, I'll make sure to post a solution should I find one, in case this can serve someone later on.